# Scraping yahoo finance comments in python with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

Brand new here and relatively new to python. I'm working on code to scrape only the comments from the yahoo finance conversation pages. I'm starting with the APPL page (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/community/). I am using the inspect element function in the Edge browser and have located the comments. Example comment:

```
 <div class="C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)" data-reactid="44">$175 tomorrow vote up or not vote down ! I vote up</div>
```

I've written the following basic code to get just the first comment (I don't need the responses). I figure if I can successfully get one comment, I can then get them all. I realize I'll have to deal with the loading of additional comments, but one step at a time.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/community/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
comm = soup.find(class_='C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)')
print(comm)
```

I keep getting "None" as the output. I don't believe javascript is involved here (I see script tags at the bottom of the HTML but not for the comments). I believe what I'm doing is too simple but I don't know how to proceed. How can I successfully scrape these comments? Definitely open to different solutions and thanks for reading.

****EDIT* 11-7-17***

I redid the program using selenium and have gotten the comments that exist on the page to appear. I'm now working on the following steps:

1) Having the program click the drop down option for Newest Reactions before scraping anything.

2) Having the program click the "Show More" button on the bottom of the page to render more comments for scraping. I want to scrape the comments over the last year but I don't see any true time stamps in the html, only "1 day ago", "two days ago", etc. I'm thinking that I could try to have the program keep clicking the "Show More" button until it reaches the first comment with a  time stamp of "1 year ago".

3) Scraping the commenter username and comment date. Ideally I would like to have the commenter username, comment date, and comment saved in a file (csv or JSON is fine).

My code is:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/YOUR_PATH_HERE/chromedriver.exe")
 driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/community/")
 timeout=10
 comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)']")
 coments = [x.text for x in comments]
 print(len(coments))
 print(coments)
```

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: comments are displayed with a click on the button "replies", you will need another tool, like selenium maybe ?

Comment: According to the docs you should use soup.select when you want to search for tags that has two or more CSS classes, like so: soup.select('div.C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)'). That'll return a list, you can iterate through.

Comment: If you only need one: soup.select_one(...).

Comment: PRMoureu - I don't need the replies to the comments. Just the original comments. Thank you for the suggestion of Selenium, I will look into it and report back.

jlaur - I've read the documentation and tried multiple ways to get the list. I get the following error:
     ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "Mb(2px)"

Comment: @jlaur I'm looking for a crawler for the conversation. Could you share your script in github? Is there some technical docs about yahoo conversation? Thx

Comment: @PRMoureu  Is there some technical docs or github about yahoo finance conversation tab? Thx