# Scraping Yahoo Finance Conversations in stock page

Tags: python, web-scraping

There has been a lot of good questions and answers talking about how to scrape hard data from Yahoo Finance. My specific goal is to scrape the "conversations" section of each stock page on Yahoo Finance, where people post their opinions about the stock. I'm really very new to web scraping, so far I've been using python requests library and regex to scrape ordinary texts. But the Yahoo Finance conversations cannot be located using the "developer" tool in Chrome. So I'm here asking for your help for the following:

- Given a single stock, scrape the conversations (all of it)
- Also the metadata of each conversation post, like time stamps and number of likes
  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
  Here is an image of the part I'm talking about:
  [Yahoo Finance Conversations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Rnv.png)

Thanks for reminding me that I should include my initial code. I borrowed codes from here: [Scraping yahoo finance comments in python with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116637/scraping-yahoo-finance-comments-in-python-with-selenium), and tried this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/...pathto.../chromedriver")
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/community/")
timeout=10
comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)']")
coments = [x.text for x in comments]
print(len(coments))
print(coments)
```

The problem is that I cannot locate the path to the elements that contain those posts. Maybe Yahoo Finance changed their format. So it should be this part that doesn't work:

```py
comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='C($c-fuji-grey-l) Mb(2px) Fz(14px) Lh(20px)']")
```

### It will only return an empty list as a result. Appreciate any help!

Update:
Here is a snapshot when I try to locate the elements that contain posts:
[Keyboard focusable dimmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rch03.png)
I guess the site does not want people to locate specific elements?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You need to show a specific problem like an error or unwanted behavior of your code.
This website is not made for such generic question.
Please explain what you tried so far and if possible add some code ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @Opsse I updated the question. Thanks for reminding me!